# Sudden black screen after login Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, login, screen, xfce

Everything worked fine (except for the audio widget), and suddenly, i boot and after i set my login credentials in the session manager, the screen goes black. How is one supposed to fix it? I find nothing on the internet about this exact problem, and the only thing i've found is unsolved.

I did nothing, not even installing new packages.

This is truly a problem for me, can somebody help?

Comment: Happens to me as well. Xubuntu will not react for ~2 seconds and then the screen goes black and switches off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem. In my case I just reinstalled Ubuntu. On my last installation, everything worked fine, but this time around I get a black screen following login. Gnome and Unity still load fine, though. I haven't installed any packages that weren't installed on my previous setup, either.